# Swift + Pubnub chat app load old message for scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, infinite-scroll, pubnub, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

In viewDidLoad of my chat view controller, I wrote `self.appDelegate.client?.historyForChannel(currentChannel, start: nil, end: nil, limit: 20, withCompletion:` and it retrieves the 20 recent messages. However, I wish to retrieve earlier/old 20 messages before these recent 20 messages for my infinite scrolling feature. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate "I need to retrieve another 20 messages" part in your question!! which 20 messages??

Comment: say the message history has 40 messages, viewDidLoad retrieves message[0]~[19], how will i retrieve [20]~[39]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the timestamp of the first message you received from Pubnub history, to receive next 20 messages:

`self.client?.historyForChannel(channel, start: lastStoredTimstamp, end: nil, limit: 20, reverse: false, withCompletion:`

I have tested it and it works well.

*Little Description:
Using only a start parameter always returns messages older than the time token provided. If you set reverse = true, you will get message newer than the time token provided.*

Please see https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/storage-and-history how the PubNub history API works with timeline diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via `UIScrollViewDelegate` (in your case, it's inside UITableView)

First of all, set the delegate of your `UITableView`.

Then, you have to override `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`, and that's a example code:

```
let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

let deltaOffset = maximumOffset - currentOffset
if (deltaOffset <= 0)
   // call to self.appDelegate.client?.historyForChannel with the offsets
)
```

The if expression would strike when you have reached to the bottom of the list.

`self.appDelegate.client?.historyForChannel` contains start & end offsets. Start can be calculated by adding +20 (declare a class variable somewhere) after every call to  `historyForChannel`, but it would work only if the objects from response have no some unique IDs.

Comment: the problem is that `start` and `end` are NSNumbers and they should be a date. That's why I can't just do a simple +20 for each scroll